# NSColor equivalent of UIColor underPageBackgroundColor to use on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscolor

I'd like to use one of the iOS patterns (`underPageBackgroundColor`), defined in `UIColor` for a Mac OS X app. Are those patterns defined in `UIColor` available on OS X? I didn't see anything like them in `NSColor`.

Basically, I'd like to use `[UIColor underPageBackgroundColor]` in a plain Cocoa app.

I could use a screenshot of the pattern and use `[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:...]`, but I'd like to use the correct API (if any).

[image: Under page background color example on iOS]

Comment: That one is _not_ available on OS X. It's defined as not applicable in `UIInterface.h`

Answer (score 3):

As of OS X Mountain Lion, there is now an official under page background color method on NSColor.